# node-gallery does not work anymore

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I'm trying to use node-gallery module.

When I'm using code

```
  app.use('/gallery', require('node-gallery')({
  staticFiles : 'resources/photos',
  urlRoot : 'gallery', 
  title : 'Example Gallery'
}));
```

It works fine, but when I'm trying to write my own function using

```
  app.use('/gallery', require('node-gallery')({
  staticFiles : 'resources/photos',
  urlRoot : 'gallery', 
  title : 'Example Gallery',
  render : false
}), function(req, res, next){

  //my func, for example:
  console.log("test");
  //return res.send(req.html);
});
```

it does not work, function is just not executed...
Documentation:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gallery
Please help me.
Thank you.